# Missing libraries after Hadoop source recompiling on ARM architecture

Tags: c++, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I've the following problem.
I'm trying to compile the following code

```
#include "hdfs.h" 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect("default", 0);
   const char* writePath = "/tmp/testfile.txt";
   hdfsFile writeFile = hdfsOpenFile(fs, writePath, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0, 0, 0);
   if(!writeFile) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for writing!\n", writePath);
      exit(-1);
   }
   char* buffer = "Hello, World!";
   tSize num_written_bytes = hdfsWrite(fs, writeFile, (void*)buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
   if (hdfsFlush(fs, writeFile)) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Failed to 'flush' %s\n", writePath); 
       exit(-1);
   }
   hdfsCloseFile(fs, writeFile);
}
```

in order to create a file on Hadoop server, via C++ (the example is taken from 
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/libhdfs.html).

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 distribution and I've recompiled the Hadoop sources on two different Architecture.

In the first case, all works fine. In the second case, with an ARM architecture,
the hdfs library has been created and I'm able to compile the main example code but I receive always the following error:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libhdfs.so.0.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've set the directory by "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = mypath" command.

Running the ldd command on the libhdfs.so file I see:

```
ldd libhdfs.so
    libjvm.so => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6714000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6 (0xb662c000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0xb675f000)
```

but libjvm.so is correctly present in the referenced directory.
Any idea on how to solve\investigate the problem? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any  architecture mismatch.

- file libhdfs.so -> gives whether it is 32-Bit or 64-Bit
- check the architecture of first occurance of libjvm.so that is present in
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH.